# Bootstrap tooltips moves up has-feedback icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When using the has-feedback class to add an icon on a form field and using the bootstrap tooltip, the icon moves up. I get the same behavior with chrome, firefox and ie.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg has-feedback">
      <input class="form-control" name="foo" placeholder="foo" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" type="text">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS File**

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Here the example
[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ls4XIy6wIL)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for it failing is this Bootstrap selector:

`.form-group-lg .form-control+.form-control-feedback {...}`

When you hover the field, the tooltip's `<div>` is inserted immediately after the input, thus breaking the `+` condition since the icon is no longer immediately following the input. A solution is to move the tooltip on the parent element, so that it doesn't interfere with children styling:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg has-feedback" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">
      <input class="form-control" name="foo" placeholder="foo" type="text">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/tohoEsh0cX